# How to add leader line to a pie chart with AphexChart when the part is super tiny?

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

I would like to add leader line and show the data for the tiny part where is missing now.

https://codepen.io/tanya-shrivastava/pen/zXNxOd

var options = {

```
      //chart option 1
      
        chart: {
          id: 'basic-pie',
          type: 'pie',
          height:500
        },

        labels:["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"],
        series: [9062,6859,838,74, 20, 12,5,3,1],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        theme: {
          palette: 'palette7'
        }
```

};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();

[image]